# Scroll bar in Excel 2016 on Mac

Tags: excel

So, I wanted to make a scroll bar in Excel, but failed due to inaccessibility of Developer tab in excel. I tried to click with the right click on the Excel menu tab but it didn't react in no way, also I tried to press Ctrl + Right click of the scroll bar on the Mac, but either way the pop up menu where you can choose to Customize the ribbon didn't appear. I ready on several how-to's that there is a Excel options where you can access Developer tab, but I simply don't have "Options" on File tab. I am using Excel 2016 on Mac. by the way, I need this scroll bar to control whether the user inputs more than max first payment for the loan ( Max first payment depends on why the loan has been taken). Maybe some of you knows better way to check whether the input is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel for Mac, developer tab is available as follows:

From the menu bar, Excel > Preferences > View > 'In Ribbon Show' (Developer Tab)

If it isn't there the Excel Preferences window has a search function, try searching 'developer'.

Good luck, hope you find it.

Answer (score 0):

**Well I found a solution to your Issue. Most times so many tabs are left out due to the average consumer not using them. I simply navigated to the FILE tab at the top left corner of Excel (2013), click on Options and clicked on Customize Ribbon.
 You should fine the Developer Tab unclicked. Below are some screenshots to help out. Hope 
this helps.**

[This Image Shows the File Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMvXw.png)

[This image shows the Options button and the Customize Ribbon Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7iW5.png)